# C++ Returning exception, Should I free resources?

Tags: c++, class, generics, exception, methods

I wrote the following implementation for my constructor:

```
template<class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Dimensions &matrix_dimensions, const T &initial_value) : dimensions(matrix_dimensions),
                                                                                 data(new T[size()]) {
    if (matrix_dimensions.getRow() <= 0 || matrix_dimensions.getCol() <= 0) {
        return IllegalInitialization();
    }
    int matrix_size = size();
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix_size; ++i) {
        data[i] = initial_value;
    }
}
```

So if an error occurs I'm returning `IllegalInitialization()` o be cached but what about the resources I have allocated using new? how to free them before returning, should I call delete?

**Just a side note:** I am new to this field so can someone check if the Code above is written well (performance wise and works as expected therotically)

Comment: any help with this?

Comment: Why do you allow `Dimensions` to hold negative values at all?    Since the number of rows and columns will not be negative, why not have them represented by an `unsigned` type?    Either way, why not have the `Dimensions` type throw the exception if given a non-positive dimension? That way, `Matrix` can SAFELY ASSUME the dimensions are valid (since an exception would be thrown before the `Matrix` is even constructed.

Comment: As to whether the `delete []` corresponding to the `new []` is performed - it depends.   If `data` is a type with a destructor that does the corresponding `delete []` on the pointer it receives, then all will be cleaned up.   But, if `data` is anything else (e.g. a raw pointer) then the memory will not be released.   Presumably the destructor of `Matrix` does such a cleanup but, in an exception is thrown in the body of the constructor of `Matrix`, the destructor of `Matrix` is not called.

Comment: How do you return a value from a constructor? Did you mean `throw` instead?

Comment: @Peter data could be anything like string, int, double or custom made class

Comment: @Zoorish - If you're initialising it with a `new` expression,  `data` could not be of type `int` or `double`.     A `new` expression can only be used to initialise pointers (of the right type) or a class with a constructor that accepts a pointer as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant `throw` rather than `return` (you can't return a value from a constructor!) so that the object's creation is cancelled, yes, you would have to `delete[] data` first.

The usual approach to this is to recursively apply the "Resource Acquisition Is Initialisation" pattern. That is, the type of `data` should *not* be a raw pointer, but instead some smart type (like `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`) that will do this deletion automatically when it goes out of scope.

*(`std::unique_ptr`, in turn, is internally exception-safe.)*

If indeed you're just early-`return`ing, then you have bigger problems — the object is left in a useless state without the owning scope knowing about it, and you have a build failure with the `return` argument (because, again, you can't return a value from a constructor!).

Comment: Take a crack at it and let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the code in the question would not ever compile, since a constructor cannot return a value.  The statement `return IllegalInitialization();` in a constructor is therefore a diagnosable error.

I assume, for the purpose of this answer, that you actually use `throw IllegalInitialization();`

Second, the code as shown POTENTIALLY has a leak.   `data` is initialised with a `new` expression, so the type of `data` must either be a pointer to a type compatible with `T`  (e.g. a pointer to a base of `T`) or it must be a class type with a constructor that accepts such a pointer (e.g. `std::unique_ptr<T>`).   If `data` is of any other type (e.g. `int`, `double`) then the initialisation of `data` is a diagnosable error since (for example) a pointer cannot be implicitly converted to an `int`.

If `data` is a raw pointer then throwing an exception in the constructor will cause a leak.   The objects or data allocated with the `new` expression will not be released.

If `data` is a class with a constructor that accepts a pointer, then there are two possibilities (in which the code will compile, and not have undefined behaviour).

1. The class constructor saves the pointer, and the destructor releases it (using a `delete []` since that corresponds to the `new` expression), then the dynamically allocated data will be safely released.  An example of such a class would be the type `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`.   This is the *only* case in which your code will avoid a leak.
2. Otherwise, there will be a memory leak.  Even if the destructor of `Matrix<T>` cleans up `data`,  the act of throwing an exception in the constructor body prevents the destructor of `Matrix<T>` being called  (a destructor can only be called for an object that has been fully constructed - and that means the constructor has completed without throwing an exception).

(There are other cases, such as `data` being an instance of a class with a destructor that uses the wrong form of `delete` expression, but those cases either give undefined behaviour or leak in other ways, so I'll ignore them).

Third (and this is more subjective), you are using a `Dimensions` type (which presumably contains a pair of integral values) to represent the matrix dimensions.   Essentially, you have a requirement, in `Matrix`, that the dimensions be positive.   Since you are throwing an exception if the dimensions are non-positive,  I suggest that check be done by the `Dimensions` class (e.g. the constructor throws if given a non-positive value,  a setter (like `SetRow()` either ignores invalid values, or throws an exception if given an invalid value).     If that is done consistently by the `Dimensions` type, then `Matrix<T>` can safely ASSUME the dimensions are valid - since it will not be possible to pass an instance of `Dimensions` with invalid values.   That means, `Matrix<T>` does not need to check.

Comment: Thanks, may you show me how my edited code should look like, I'm working on a big project and it would be really helpful to get a sample. thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I've described what your code needs to do to be safe (or safer, at least) - updating your code is your job.   This not a free coding service - and you'll learn more by working out how to do it yourself, than you will if people simply spoon-feed you with code.    Also, consider using standard containers (`std::vector`, etc) - while it is possible to use them in an unsafe manner, if you read the documentation and follow guidance, they tend to be safer by default than hand-rolling your own code that does memory allocation.